# SQL Server 2014 AOAG + Replication?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, transactional-replication

I have an existing SQL Server (2014) setup using Always On Availability Groups. All the documentation says I should not try to install replication (aka distributor role) on any of the servers participating in the Always On Availability Groups.

Why does the documentation warn against doing that, will it break Always On? Does Always On prevent replication from working? Or is there some other reason?

Answer (score 4):

IN SQL Server 2014 and earlier, the replication jobs will not continue to work after failover if you put the Distribution Database in an AG.

If you upgrade to SQL Server 2016 or 2017, this becomes a supported configuration:

> SQL Server 2017 CU6 and SQL Server 2016 SP2-CU3 introduces support for
>   replication distribution database in an AG

[Set up replication distribution database in Always On availability group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/configure-distribution-availability-group?view=sql-server-2017)